# Unable to find method ''com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, sdk

Im having an issue with syncing the gradle for my android studio project

```
Unable to find method ''com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)''
'com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)'
```

Here's my project gradle and app gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is the app gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'

}

android {
    compileSdk 33
    testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources true
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tradesource"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'com.example.tradesource'
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.4.0'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.8'
    androidTestImplementation project(path: ':app')
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Tried to change plugins for Android Gradle and Google Services Plugin to versions 7.0.4 and 4.3.10 so they are "compatible" but this did not work.

Not sure what else to do